# Kotlin coroutine java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete even though task returns a value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase with await(), 
when I am trying to do this without a result wrapper the code works , but the same thing crashes with:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete"

The next code crash

```
  suspend fun isUserRegisteredOnServer(): Result<Exception, Boolean> =
    try {
        val result = userRef.get().await().exists()
        Result.build { result }
    }
    catch (e : Exception) {
        Result.Error(e)
    }
```

The following doesn't

```
suspend fun tempIsRegistered() : Boolean
{
    return userRef.get().await().exists()
}
```

Result class:

```
sealed class Result <out E,out V > {

    data class Value<out V>(val value : V) : Result<Nothing, V>()
    data class Error<out E>(val error : E) : Result<E, Nothing>()

    companion object Factory
    {
        inline fun <V> build(function : () -> V): Result<Exception, V> =
            try {
                Value(function.invoke())
            }catch (e: Exception) {
                Error(e)
            }
    }
}
```

It's also worth noting I am calling theses functions from

```
CoroutineScope(IO).launch {}
```

Stack trace:

```
2019-09-05 18:50:54.121 23507-23561/E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: , PID: 23507
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source:29)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.zzb(Unknown Source:121)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu.getResult(Unknown Source:12)
        at firebase.database.FirestoreDatabaseRepository.fetchUserLists(FirestoreDatabaseRepository.kt:79)
        at com.mainfragment.MainFragmentViewModel$handleEvent$1.invokeSuspend(MainFragmentViewModel.kt:74)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:238)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and use the Tasks API:

```
try {
    val result = Tasks.await(userRef.get(), 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    Result.build { result }
}
catch (e : Exception) {
    Result.Error(e)
}
```